# HTML Images not lining up

Tags: html, responsive-design

This is my page http://suntmormon.ro/jarman-home-page/ and I want to know why my four smaller images are staggering and not aligned. I use wordpress.

Here is my current code

```
[one_half padding="0 0 0 5px"]
<link><img class="alignnone  wp-image-203 link_img" src="http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Vizioneaza-un-mesaj-mormon-final-optiunea-2.png" alt="rounded_corners" /></a>
[/one_half][one_half_last padding="0 13px 0 5px"]
<link><img class="alignnone  wp-image-210 link_img" src="http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Ce-facem-noi-final.png" alt="Munți de urcat" width="465" height="232" /></a><link><img class="alignnone  wp-image-222 link_img" src="http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Ce-credem-final.png" alt="În ce cred Mormonii" width="465" height="233" /></a>
[/one_half_last]
<br clear="all">

[one_fourth]
Elena
<link><img class="mormon-thumbnail" src="http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/elena.png" height="168" width="180" alt="" /></a>
<link>Descarcă</a>
[/one_fourth]

[one_fourth]
Sergiu
<link><img class="mormon-thumbnail" src="http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/sergiu.png" height="168" width="180" alt="" /></a>
<link>Descarcă</a>
[/one_fourth]

[one_fourth]
Cătălin şi Carmen
<link><img class="mormon-thumbnail" src="http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/foteas1.png" height="168" width="180" alt="" /></a>
<a href="http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Catalin-si-Carmen-Fotea.mpg" download="Catalin-Carmen">Descarcă</a>
[/one_fourth]
[one_fourth]
Alin
<link><img class="mormon-thumbnail" src="http://suntmormon.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/alin.png" height="168" width="180" alt="" /></a>
<link>Descarcă</a>
[/one_fourth]
```

I tried a clear break and that did not work.

Comment: Please include some code and/or what you have tried in your question. Linking to a page will be of no value to anyone who comes across this question in the future once you have fixed the problem on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current simplified code is this

HTML:

```
<div class="content-column one_fourth"></div>
<p></p>
<br>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

All you need to do is either:

1. Change the css for the **p** element to ***margin-bottom: 0em;***

OR

2. Delete that **p** element from the html.

AND

3. Delete the **br** element from the html.

Comment: Easier said than done. Not sure where to access that.

Comment: Its not a good practice, but if you can't manage to edit the html to remove the `p`elements, add this css to your site:

`p { margin-bottom: 0em !important; }`

and delete all the `br` elements.

see if that helps.

Comment: I tried a wordpress plugin that stops wordpress from adding in paragraphs but it broke my page. Now the pictures aren't there at all.

Comment: Nevermind, site just lags now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete all p elements and br elements
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it indirectly helped me.